# PostgreSQL server prevents hibernation

Tags: postgresql

I've configured my Synology [DS918+](https://www.synology.com/en-uk/products/DS918+) Diskstation so that it goes into HDD hibernation when the disks are not being used. I've had it configured like that for a year and it's worked pretty well so far.
Recently, I've installed a Docker container for [PostgreSQL](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) on this system for some development. The database is working fine, but it prevents the Diskstation from hibernating.

- Also after a fresh restart of the diskstation
- Works again if I turn the container off
- Works fine if I run [MariaDB](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/) in the same conditions
- No other service or app is trying to access the database.

I suspect that the Postgres server is constantly doing some work in the background.
I'm not yet very familiar with Postgres, but is there a way to edit its configuration so that it allows hibernation?
I found the config file, but I couldn't identify which option to edit - if there is any.

Comment: Did you install Docker on your system or your Synology device?\

Comment: [Docker](https://www.synology.com/en-global/dsm/packages/Docker) is running on my Synology device.

Comment: Are there open database connections or is the database idle? The background disk activity may be cause by vacuum/autovacuum tasks and/or log files.

Comment: No there is no open connection. The database should be idle. I have enabled the logs by adding `logging_collector = on` and `log_min_messages = debug5` in the config. I have also disabled autovacuum with `autovacuum = off`. After restarting the postgresql server, I observe the following [logs](https://ibb.co/s5T22Nb). Not sure what it means, but could it what's preventing the system to be fully idle?

Comment: I made more tests. Disabling the logging with `logging_collector = off` and the autovacuum with `autovacuum = off` allows my NAS to go to hibernation. As soon as I enable one of them, hibernation doesn't work. I can live without the logging. However, is it recommended to have autovacuum off? Can we tweak the settings so that it is triggered less often? like once a day?